# Which of these CSS methods would you use?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I recently came across this code which uses a way, which I've never used before, to position 3 columns on a page. I have included this method in my code below in GROUP 2. I use GROUP 1 to achieve the same task myself. Now I know writing mark-up such as CSS and HTML, much like programming, is mostly up to the programmer - provided efficiency etc is not a factor. But in this case, what do you guys think are the pros and cons of GROUP 1 vs. GROUP 2?

As an example, since GROUP 2 is using negative  margin technique, if the #Left2 div comes before #Middle2 and #Right2, it will go behind #Header2 and not even visible on the page. Personally, I think GROUP 2 method is weaker and less robust since some browsers may not position the divs correctly because of the negative margins. So, what do you guys think?

The writer of GROUP 2 code has apparently used it from a book by Zoe Mickley Gillenwater called Flexible Web Design Creating Liquid and Elastic Layouts with CSS. **So I wonder if coding of GROUP 2 is bad practice, why is it in a design book? And if it is not bad practice, why not?**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Layout Test</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Header1">GROUP 1</div>

        <div id="Left1">
            Left
        </div>

        <div id="Middle1">
            Middle
            <br />
            Middle
            <br />
            Middle
            <br />
            Middle
            <br />
            Middle
        </div>
        <div id="Right1">
            Right
        </div>

        <br class="Clear" />

        <div id="Footer1">Footer</div>

        <br /><br /><br />

        <div id="Header2">GROUP 2</div>



        <div id="Wrapper">
            <div id="Middle2">
                Middle
                <br />
                Middle
                <br />
                Middle
                <br />
                Middle
                <br />
                Middle
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="Right2">
            Right
        </div>
        <div id="Left2">
            Left
        </div>

        <br class="Clear" />

        <div id="Footer2">Footer</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body { background-color: Gray; }

#Header1 { background-color: Lime; }

#Left1 { background-color: Fuchsia; width: 25%; float: left; }

#Middle1 { background-color: Orange; width: 50%; float: left; }

#Right1 { background-color: Purple; width: 25%; float: left; }

#Footer1 { background-color: Yellow; }



.Clear { clear: both; }


#Header2 { background-color: Lime; }

#Left2 { background-color: Fuchsia; width: 25%; float: left; margin-left: -100%; }

#Middle2 { background-color: Orange; margin: 0 25%; }

#Right2 { background-color: Purple; width: 25%; float: left; margin-left: -25%; }

#Footer2 { background-color: Yellow; }

#Wrapper { width: 100%; float: left; }
```

They both look the same at the end:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of using this form, will directly affect the site navigation
If you're surfing the header it can jump to the opposite side of where it is expected
if I mistake not witnessed using this browser for visually impaired

Comment: You are referring to GROUP 2, right? The weird thing about this is, the writer of GROUP 2 code had apparently used it from a book by Zoe Mickley Gillenwater called Flexible Web Design Creating Liquid and Elastic Layouts with CSS. So I wonder if this code is bad practice, why this code is in a design book? And if it is not bad practice, why not?

Comment: other ways of doing the same thing, does not mean they are the best ... you can put the div left on right, the header on footer using negatives to "adjust", but does not mean it's the best way, but a different way. takes into account the maintenance that would be a strange layout with negative alignment. I use negative adjustment when I want to actually reverse the position of an item, but only in lists and columns but not in a layout

Answer (score 0):

I vote for group 1. :) Based on your illustration your trying to make a three column in a page. So the best approach for that is to use float:left; in the left part and float:right; on the right part. That's always the good practice for three columns. Using negative(-) to achieve it is a very bad practice and is a very big NO.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm just copying the comment I just made to the previous 'answer':
The weird thing about this is, the writer of GROUP 2 code had apparently used it from a book by Zoe Mickley Gillenwater called Flexible Web Design Creating Liquid and Elastic Layouts with CSS. So I wonder if this code is bad practice, why this code is in a design book? And if it is not bad practice, why not?

Comment: At what specific chapter did that author get the idea from the book. I wanna search and see it myself.

Comment: Apparently Chapter 4. I haven't read the book myself, but have the ebook version. I just did a search on it. Check out page 113.

Comment: uhm.. I see.. I understand now his point of view. But still I'm not convince to do it that way. Me as a web developer if I'm doing 3 columns I use float:left; to the left side then float:right; on the right side. and for the middle I'm using float:left; and just add margin to adjust on the left. I'm not using negative(-) on doing web because it gets nasty when you change browsers and different screen resolutions. But using it on mobile devices is a different story. I dont have an idea how it works there. :)

Comment: Great, thanks very much. I don't like the negative approach either (and have never used them).

I would do it almost the same way as you (see GROUP 1 divs, I wrote those). But why would you use 'float: right' for the Right div? why not use all 'float: left' as in my solution in GROUP 1. They both would end up the same, but just curious... :)

Comment: nah.. its the same. But i like to use float:right; because its proper. :)

Comment: Super. Thanks for your responses bot :)

Answer (score 0):

Group 1 is the way to go.

IMHO, negative margins, although possible, are more in the way of *hacking* your layout to do something you want than actually producing the intended effect the first time. The main problem here is that different browsers (and different versions of the same browser - *yes, I'm talking to you IE!!!*) tend to behave wildly the more you hack the layout.

Furthermore, if you are trying to make it usable to the broader audience, you should take in to account the behaviour and parsing limitations in today's reality: mobile devices. I bet a few of them filp out at this type of coding.

So, in my experience, I would advise against it.

Comment: Thanks very much. I totally agree with you :-)